# SQL Server : drop all non-system tables except?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to drop all non-system tables except for 2 tables. But it always deletes
all the tables.

What am I doing wrong with this code?

```
/* Drop all tables */
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254)

SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] 
                    FROM sysobjects 
                    WHERE [type] = 'U' 
                      AND category = 0  
                      AND name NOT IN ('JobSource', 'City') 
                    ORDER BY [name])

WHILE @name IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
   SELECT @SQL = 'DROP TABLE [dbo].[' + RTRIM(@name) +']'

   EXEC (@SQL)
   PRINT 'Dropped Table: ' + @name

   SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] 
                   FROM sysobjects 
                   WHERE [type] = 'U' 
                     AND category = 0 
                     AND [name] > @name 
                   ORDER BY [name])
END
```

Comment: I would recommend to use the more focused `sys.tables` catalog view - then you only get views, and there's no need to remember those cryptic `type` values (like `U` for table ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the name condition to the `WHERE` clause of your inner loop, when you update the @name variable all the way at the end.

Change your loop like this (notice the last `SELECT` statement):

```
WHILE @name IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT @SQL = 'DROP TABLE [dbo].[' + RTRIM(@name) +']'
    EXEC (@SQL)
    PRINT 'Dropped Table: ' + @name
    SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] = 'U' AND category = 0 and name not in ('JobSource', 'City') ORDER BY [name])
END
```

Also, you probably don't need the `AND [name] > @name` in that clause so I took that out.